# Eclipselink detaching entity and performing insert for existing entity

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, eclipselink, weblogic12c

I have following M-M relationship scenario

Employee and Project are connected with each other by EmployeeProjectRlsp

I have below Relationship defined

In Employee

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
private List<EmployeeProjectRlsp> employeeProjectRlsp;
```

In Project

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
private List<EmployeeProjectRlsp> employeeProjectRlsp;
```

In EmployeeProjectRlsp

```
// bi-directional many-to-one association to Agreement
@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID", nullable = false)
private Employee employee;

// bi-directional many-to-one association to Category
@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinColumn(name = "PROJECT_ID", nullable = false)
private Project project;
```

Now issue : We are doing persist for each employee we have everything as cascade. Here requirement is if Project is not there in DB then create new Project

Coding is doing something like below

```
Project dbProject = projectDAO.getProject(xmlProject);
if(dbProject != null)
     xmlProject = dbProject;
EmployeeProjectRlsp employeeProjectRlsp =    emproRlspFactory.getEmployeeProjectRlsp(xmlProject, xmlEmployee);
xmlEmploye.addEmployeeProjectRlsp(employeeProjectRlsp);
employeDao.persist(xmlEmploye);
```

EmployeeProjectRlspFactory

```
EmployeeProjectRlsp getEmployeeProjectRlsp(Project project, Employee employee){
    EmployeeProjectRlsp employeeProjectRlsp = new EmployeeProjectRlsp();
    employeeProjectRlsp.setEmployee(employee);
    employeeProjectRlsp.setProject(project);
    //rest of attribute
```

}

when I run above code in single thread environment everything works fine.
when I am having 100 thread coming in same time I am getting integrity constrain on Project Object where project is saved days back.

I have all the Entities and their relationship marked with cascade

```
cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }
```

Now this issue of integrity constrain coming to any of existing object coming from DB by either egar/lezy fetch or DAO call its keep failing at random places.

Can someone help me here what need to be done.

Comment: Before I get too deep into the question, the first thing that struck me is you describe your env. as M-M, but you have 1-M relationships on your entities, vs M-M. Can you clarify?

Comment: He is using an intermediate entity, with 1:M going to it rather than a JPA M:M between the main entities.

Comment: Your emproRlspFactory.getEmployeeProjectRlsp is likely using a different entityManager context from the one used for the employeDao.persist call, so that the employeeProjectRlsp is a detached instance.  By then calling persist you are telling JPA to insert the entity, and the persist cascades to the I assume existing emproRlspFactory and Project instance.  Since these weren't read from the same context, they too must be inserted as if they are new.  Try using merge instead of persist.

Comment: I have added code for factory but its just simple factory class give me new object of entity I have to create.

Comment: I tried  merge as well but it still failing.

Comment: Is the project causing the constraint being reused amongst the different threads?  How was it read in and how is it being passed around?  what exactly is the integrety constraint - is it a duplicate ID or something else?  What do your factory methods look like, could they not be thread safe?

Comment: Looks like i got the issue but still looking for solution. All of my dao injected by spring and they have parent generic denic dao injecting entitymanager, can this injection of EM caus issue with detaching fetched object and reinserting them with lastly injected EM.